# htaccess rewriterule for query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm new with RewriteRule in .htaccess file.

I'm trying to change the url from:

```
http://www.example.com/abc.php?val
```

to:

```
http://www.example.com/def-ght
```

I have passed more than 3 days for googling and reading articles about how to write RewriteRule for query string to redirect to other page. However, I'm still in the block way and can't find out the solution.

Can you guide me to solve this problem, please?

Comment: If you could clearly define the relationship between `abc.php?val` and `def-ght` that would be helpful for us.

Comment: Is `def = abc.php` and `val = ght` ?

Comment: it's all different value

Comment: Without a possible relation between any of them, it'd be difficult to know what actually you're trying to achieve.

Comment: My idea is to use redirect 301 instead of 404 when the url doesn't exist